# Add rows to a DataTable from a query expression result

Tags: linq

I am trying to dynamically add rows to a datatable from a query expression result. However, I am getting the below exception :
"Cannot cast DBNull.Value to type 'System.Int16'. Please use a nullable type."

This is my code:

```
foreach (var linqItem in linqResult)
                    resultDT.Rows.Add(linqItem.GetType().GetProperties().Select(p => p.GetValue(linqItem, null)).ToArray());
```

Please help me figure out figure out this issue.

Additional Code:

```
 var linqResult = from misDTRow in misUserDetailsDT.AsEnumerable()
                             join deptDTRow in departmentInfoDT.AsEnumerable()
                             on misDTRow.Field<Int16>("DepartmentID") equals deptDTRow.Field<Int32>("DeptID")
                             select
                             new
                             {
                                 Username = misDTRow["LoginName"],
                                 EmployeeID = misDTRow["EmployeeID"],
                                 EmployeeName = misDTRow["EmployeeName"],
                                 FoundIn = misDTRow["FoundIn"],
                                 StatusInMIS = (bool)misDTRow["IsActive"] == true ? "Inactive" : "Active",
                                 Department = deptDTRow["DeptName"]
 };
```

DataTable Creation:

```
 DataTable resultDT = new DataTable();
 PropertyInfo[] propInfo = linqResult.First().GetType().GetProperties();
 foreach (PropertyInfo property in propInfo)
     resultDT.Columns.Add(property.Name, property.PropertyType);
```

I am creating the DataTable dynamically from the query result.

Comment: You should provide more code, the type of linqItem, the schema of Datatable

Comment: I have provided the additional code as required. Hope that helps you figure out a solution.

Answer (score 0):

try change to int? instead of int

> "Cannot cast DBNull.Value to type 'System.Int16'. Please use a nullable type."

this is because you trying to cast the nullable type to int.

Check your database table which column allow null. Then you can cast it to nullable type.

For example :

```
misDTRow.Field<Int?>("DepartmentID") equals deptDTRow.Field<Int?>("DeptID")
```

Comment: Actually I am adding rows to the misUserDetailsDT table, setting value only for a few columns. So the rest of the columns are being set to null. Now when I am adding the query result to the 'resultDT' table, how can I cast those null values.

Comment: Although DataColumn has a property 'AllowDBNull', which by default is set to true, why does it still forbid adding a row which is having null values ?

Comment: you hit the error at this code "                    resultDT.Rows.Add(linqItem.GetType().GetProperties().Select(p => p.GetValue(linqItem, null)).ToArray());"?

Comment: Yes @DevProve, i got an error at that row. Also when I try to execute this code : linqResult.ElementAt(5000); I am getting the same error.

Comment: Can you try to cast the property of the anonymous object to nullable type? like:
Username = misDTRow["LoginName"],
EmployeeID = (int?)misDTRow["EmployeeID"],
EmployeeName = misDTRow["EmployeeName"],
FoundIn = misDTRow["FoundIn"],
StatusInMIS = (bool)misDTRow["IsActive"] == true ? "Inactive" : "Active",
                                 Department = deptDTRow["DeptName"]